# Can't add invitation to calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, calendar, ical

My girlfriend sent me an invitation from an Apple device to an alias that sends to both my work and home e-mail addresses.  I clicked on the `Accept` button and it says that I `Accepted` but I don't see the event on my iPhone or on `www.icloud.com`.  None of these e-mail addresses -- home, work, or alias -- match my Apple ID.  Is there a way I can get this into my calendar?  I tried forwarding the work e-mail to my home address and adding the event from the `.ics` file but I get `This invitation data is out of date` when I try and do this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the "this information data is out of date" message on my iPhone, and the work-around for me (based on a different discussion thread) was to temporarily disable wifi. With wifi disabled, the "add to calendar" option re-appeared. Go figure.

Comment: Disabling Wi-Fi made no difference for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the receiving email as an "Alternate Email" in your Apple ID settings. Visit http://appleid.apple.com, login, and look at the Alternate Email section.

Once you've added it as an alternate, you can then successfully accept calendar invites sent to that email and have them show up on your iCloud calendar.

Comment: I can't find the invitation in my home e-mail.  Luckilyh, it still exists at work.  I've added my alias to my Apple ID as you suggested.  However, I still can't get that invite to show up in `iCloud`.  I forwarded the `.ics` file to my home e-mail address but when I click on the .ics file I get `This invitation data is out of date`.

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to forward an old invite. It will work only going forward. Have it resent.